# How to find the file that has a word i want to modify in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to modify some of part of HTML but I am stuck at this moment.

I am looking for a word, the file that includes the word that I want to modify or delete on HTML exactly.

please check following html code :

```
<input class="wSearchField no-filter" type="text" 
data-class="no-filter: !@KEY_FEATURE.filter" 
data-attr="placeholder:  @KEY_LNG.Search;aria-label:@KEY_LNG.Search" data-value="KEY_SEARCH_TERM" 
data-focus="@focusin_searchbox(true)" 
data-blur="$sc.handleFocusOut('focusin_searchbox')|timeout:200" 
data-keyup="$mc.newSearch(node.value, event.keyCode),$sc.handleKey(event)|debounce:150" 
tabindex="7" placeholder="-Search-" aria-label="-Search-">
```

I want to modify right here `placeholder="-Search-"` (at the last line) as `placeholder="-"`

Which file does have the word "**Search**"? I am not able to find it out of many files.

Thanks have a great day

Comment: Javascript is not suited for searching **in** files. Many text editors and IDEs have this ability. For example Notepad++ has the ability to *Find In Files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the file related to that text. it's included on javascript file as a part of code.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "-");
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYVgmm

Comment: first of all thanks for your opinion. but the description is not file but element when open using search of chrome(Ctrl+Shift+I). actually the decription doesn't exist as a file.

Answer (score 0):

you can set by javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wSearchField").placeholder = "Type name here..";
```

or you can try using jquery

```
$('.wSearchField').attr("placeholder", "Type your answer here");
```